# Дубликаты меток: латиница и кириллица

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка с латинской c (3976 вопросов):

[c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

А есть метка с кириллической с (89 вопросов):

[с#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%23)

Не худо бы перенести второе в первое и удалить кириллическую метку.

**UPD.** Голосуем за синонимы:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/synonyms

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/synonyms

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/многопоточность/synonyms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/synonyms)

И не только за эти. Список всех предложенных синонимов [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). Чтобы проголосовать за синоним, кликните по основной метке и отдайте свой голос за или против предложенных синонимов.

Comment: Подсказка: чтобы сослаться на тег, можно использовать следующий код: `[tag:c#]`. В посте такой тег будет выглядеть как тег, а не голая ссылка.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду. Как пользователь SO, я совершенно неопытен :).

Answer (score 7):

Специально для таких целей в движке StackOverflow есть фича "Синонимы меток".  Чтобы добавить синоним к метке, кликните по метке и выберите ссылку "Синонимы" под описанием. Ваш общий рейтинг должен быть выше 1250, а рейтинг по метке - выше 5 ([привилегия "Создавать Синонимы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)). Если рейтинг синонима достигнет 4, он будет утверждён, и вопросы с меткой-синонимом перейдут под основную метку. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) можно просмотреть список неутверждённых синонимов и проголосовать за них.

Comment: Рейтинг 5+ надо иметь в исходной метке, в дублирующей метке или в обеих метках? А то рейтинг в латинской метке [tag:c#] у меня есть, а в кириллической [tag:с#] получить его затруднительно. :)

Comment: Судя по всему, в исходной. Точно сказать не могу, у меня 5+ репутация по обеим меткам (латинской и кириллической), и я не смог найти среди своих меток пару синонимичных с рейтингами 5+ и 5-, чтобы проверить это предположене.

Comment: Вот, нашёл! По метке `thread` у меня рейтинг 6, а по метке `потоки` - 4. Я могу предложить `потоки` как синоним метки `thread`, но не наоборот. Было бы неплохо чётко описать это в справке.

Comment: Ещё загвоздка. Если я правильно понял справку, для голосования за синоним (в отличие от создания синонима) достаточно "answer score >= 5". У меня оный равен 11, но возможности голосовать я не вижу (или я слепой). Мне всё-таки нужно 1250 репы или нет? / Кстати, что касается потоков, то вообще-то лучше наоборот "потоки" сделать основным, по-моему.

Comment: @Athari, насчёт того, какой тег сделать основным - отдельный вопрос, я синоним назначил ради эксперимента, и если вы считаете, что это неверно - голосуйте против. Я бы основным сделал тег `многопоточность`, но у меня по нему слишком низкий рейтинг. Голосовать можно на [странице с описанием тега](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/thread/synonyms), там перечислены все предложенные синонимы.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Тогда голосуем: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/synonyms

Comment: *хитрая ухмылка* Ща у вас будет 5+ в [tag:многопоточность]. :) Надо только дождаться утверждения правок и обновления счётчиков (по-моему, они кэшируются).

Comment: @fori1ton для [tag:многопоточность] есть [tag:multithreading], лучше их связать.

Comment: @andreycha, здравая мысль. Создал синоним, можете голосовать.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил ссылку на c++ (та же проблема).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вы ж ромбовый модератор. Вы не можете собственноручно утвердить синонимы, не дожидаясь результатов голосования?

Comment: @Athari, видимо, на SO полная демократия) Кстати, как выяснилось, некоторые синонимы могут создавать только модераторы. В частности, это относится к синонимам-версиям. Простой пользователь не может предложить синоним `visual-studio-2010` (и других версий) для тега `visual-studio`.

Comment: Могу. Идея в том, чтобы все потихоньку начали добавлять ссылки на метки для добавления синонимов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А можете, пожалуйста, добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Готово!

Answer (score 3):

есть ещё и метка [с](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81) (кириллица).

вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435069/178576) её (первоначально) и использовал автор.

я бы назначил синоним, но у меня недостаточно репутации по метке [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) (латиница).

Comment: Готово! Проголосовать можно [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/synonyms).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, для того, чтобы голосовать, тоже не хватает репутации.

Comment: Я без голосования назначил. Думаю, много возражающих не найдется.